# Lightning recordData - Namespace in Managed Package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, namespace

We are using lightning:recordData to create new records from a lightning component.  In my dev org I can so something like:

```
        cmp.find("myRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
        "MyObject__c", // sObject type (objectApiName)
        null,      // recordTypeId
        false,     // skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = cmp.get("v.newRecord");
            var error = cmp.get("v.newRecordError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                helper.showToastErrorMessage("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                return;
            }
        })
    );
```

When packed and deployed this fails with an error:

> You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.

I'm pretty sure this is because MyObject__c is a custom object that has a namespace after being deployed.

What is the recommended method of getting the namespace so that I can have a conditional in my code to prepend this object name with a namespace when its running in a managed package?  The namespace of this object will be the same namespace of the component itself.

Comment: Have you considered developing in DX/scratch orgs to save yourself the hassle of namespace issues?

Comment: @sfdcfox, yes, but that is not happening right away.